# When Photoshop Elements is running, all windows lose sizing controls

Tags: big-sur, window-manager, adobe-photoshop

I notice I am unable to resize any windows on my desktop (Big Sur). The mouse pointer does not change to sizing controls or goes back to pointer immediately.

This happens only when Photoshop Elements is active in the background. Quitting Elements restores normal function to all windows.

Any idea why is this and can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: Does it recur after a reboot? Does it happen every time or is it intermittent? Is Elements running fullscreen or windowed? Is Elements up to date? [ https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/release-note/update.html ] Have you asked Adobe about this?

Comment: @Tetsujin Interesting questions. This seems to happen when a file is opened in the Elements, usually minimized. When closing the file the situation restores to normal. I have 20210811 version and Elements does not suggest updates even with updates turned on. Has been rebooted. I haven't yet asked adobe.

Comment: Your version is well out of date. I'd update first - see my link - then next would be to ask Adobe.